# creating a clone of a site is good idea for project?

Tags: web-development

I am trying my hand in python, Django, JQuery.. etc to make a clone of imdb site. Currently I'm in web-development from past 10 months on same technologies. In my spare time I want to develop a side-project which may look good on resume.
I came up with an *idea*, to make a clone of imdb.com. But after 2 weeks of development I stopped.

reasons: *its not different*

1. Why create another imdb?
2. I'm not improving it?
3. Face it, it will be sub standard of original one.

The need for the project is to showcase my skills in above technologies but at same time I want it to be useful.

Comment: In my opinion the main decision factor for a hobby project would be: will you still be motivated to work on it in 3 months? That motivation might come from scratching an itch, learning new stuff, providing something useful for others, ... No matter where it comes from, will it still be true in 3 months? 6 months? A year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you said reminds me of a quote from John Carmack on the subject:

> In the information age, the barriers [to entry into programming] just aren't there. 
>   The barriers are self imposed. If you want to set off and go develop some grand new 
>   thing, you don't need millions of dollars of capitalization. You need enough pizza and 
>   Diet Coke to stick in your refrigerator, a cheap PC to work on, and the dedication to 
>   go through with it. We slept on floors. We waded across rivers.
>
> — *John Carmack*

I would say more important than the pizza, Diet Coke, and cheap PC is the dedication.  If your heart isn't into it, you'll never make a decent program.  And since making something which has already been done before is a strong demotivator, logically you should strive to do something which has never been done before.

Oddly enough, it doesn't even have to be that particularly useful since at least for me, that doesn't seem to be so important.  It just has to be something which nobody has attempted before.

Of course, on a resume, flashy is better, but flashy is not as important as getting it done, so focus on developing something you want to see finished.  You can always go back and improve on it (adding a better interface or whatever).

When you're coding every night to finish something you enjoy working on, then you'll wind up with a marvelous little project that works and *is* impressive.  If you quit half-way, then it doesn't matter how useful or flashy it would have been.  It didn't finish.

Comment: @user2211729 Hope that helps.  Just telling you what works for me.  :)

Comment: working on poll website on which user can create polls on various subjects .... books, movie, technology etc.

Comment: @user2211729 Sounds like a solid idea.  Keep it simple at first, though.

Comment: although i'm trying Bootstrap for interface but i'll keep it minimalistic.. thanks. i'm motivated by ur feedback

Comment: should i require login before  user can poll or should i keep it open so that anybody without login credential can poll ? a bit confused on this

Comment: @user2211729 Depends what you want to do.  Generally speaking, it's better to reduce the number of actively polling users, but there is nothing stopping you from polling without login credentials.  If you need to poll and a user who isn't logged in can access that page, then polling could happen without logging in.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't there something you need for *yourself* ? Think about it, find things you need and which don't exist yet on the market (or are expensive, or have weaknesses which make them unacceptable for you), and make those things.

Examples of my previous projects:

- Something which doesn't exist: an app which can transform an ordinary screen in a tactile one by using two webcams specifically positioned in front of it.
- Something which exists but is expensive: a bug tracking system.
- Something which exists and is affordable, but has weaknesses: a sync tool which will work on Windows and sync files from one PC to another:

  1. Without writing metadata files anywhere (this excludes SyncToy),
  2. With the support for Unicode (this excludes SyncBack),
  3. Without the 260 characters limitation for paths (this excludes nearly every sync app for Windows I know).

What's the point in making a clone of IMDB? Or Facebook? Or Google Maps?

- Either your sole motivation is *their* success. In this case, stop right now. *Their* success is not due exclusively to the product itself, but the opportunities they took, their marketing scheme, and sometimes billions of dollars they invested in it. Not counting that most of those products were written by hundreds of developers, and would be slightly complicated to redo *alone*.
- Or you're simply curious about the issues they got, or have a very specific need those sites don't fulfill well, or just for fun, then do it. Don't compare yourself to *them* : it's *your* project; it's not a clone of YouTube, but a way to see how to handle large amount of videos; it's not a clone of Twitter, but an experiment you do to see how to store small chunks of text in a way optimized for fast retrieval when they are recent, but not when they are older.

Comment: Wow, that stereo vision project sound fun. Is it open source?

Comment: @Vorac: sadly, like most of my projects, it's completely unfinished and barely works on my own machine. I started open sourcing more and more projects, but this one is still too raw and broken for being useful to anyone.

Comment: I would still be interested to see what technologies you are using, what is the scope of the project and to monitor it's progress. Might as well motivate me to do that eye tracker I've been thinking about.